# Why isn't possible to have the Taylor expansion of $\text{exp}{(-\frac{1}{x^2})}$ based on the original criteria?

Tags: real-analysis

The following theorem is from the book Advanced Calculus by P M Fitzpatrick :

[image]

Considering the criteria in the mentioned theorem, if we define $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      \text {exp}{(-\frac{1}{x^2})} & x\neq 0 \\
      0 & x=0 
   \end{cases},$$

this function must be possible to be written $f(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$ **for any** $\mathbf {x}$. But actually $f(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k$ holds only if $x=0$. Why is there a contradiction?

Comment: The problem must lie in the second condition (the one involving $r$ and $M$). Actually showing that this condition doesn't hold for your $f$ — without appealing to this theorem — looks messy to me, though...

Comment: Have you found an $M$ and $r$ such that $|f^{(n)}(x)|<M^n$ for all $n$ and all $x\in [-r,r]$?

Comment: @Dr.MV - I suppose that for any x∈[−r,r], $|f^{(n)}(x)|$ is finite, so we take M as the max of them (?)

Comment: How do you know that they are bounded as $n$ increases?

Comment: @Dr.MV - just guessing! I think, yes the problem should lie on finding $M$ and $r$ ...

Comment: @L.G. It's easier just to show that the function is not represented by its Taylor Series.  Then, obviously one cannot find a suitable $M$ and $r$.